# Problem building a silverlight project with MVVM-light on my PC. On other computers it builds

Tags: silverlight, xaml, compiler-errors, mvvm-light

I work in a team on a silverlight project. This silverlight project uses MVVM-light. When I want to build the project I get the following two errors:

Error 1 :
The type 'EventTrigger' does not support direct content.
I get this error on this xaml code:

`<HyperlinkButton x:Name="HyperlinkButtonSelectAll" Content="Select all" IsTabStop="False" Height="20" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectAllPluginsCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</HyperlinkButton>`

I get this error on the GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command tag.

Error 2 :
The property '_UnknownContent' does not exist on the type 'EventTrigger' in the XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity'.

For this error I do not have specific line and columnnumbers.

The strange thing however is that my colleagues don't have this issue. Even if they take the latest version from source control. I however have these errors. I already tried to delete the complete solution and get it back from sourcesafe, but I keep getting these errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Michiel

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have a different version of Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio or Blend installed than they do. The key here is what version of the System.Windows.Interactivity assembly you have referenced. If you find that you have a different version of that assembly on your machine than your co-workers, I suggest you store a working version of that assembly in source control and reference that one from the project.

Comment: Hey,
We use the same version of Silverlight Tools and it's the same version of Blend. The System.Windows.Interactivity assembly that we reference is stored on a network drive (with all the necessary rights for it). So it is the same too.